# Passing arguments containing spaces from one script to another in Perl

Tags: perl, arguments, parent-child

I am trying to pass arguments from one Perl script to another. Some of the arguments contain spaces.

I am reading in a comma-delimited text file and splitting each line on the comma.

```
my ($jockey, $racecourse, $racenum, $hnamenum, $trainer, $TDRating, $PRO) = split(/,/, $line);
```

The data in the comma-delimited text file look as follows:

```
AARON LYNCH,WARRNAMBOOL,RACE 1,DAREBIN (8),ERIC MUSGROVE,B,1
```

When I print out each variable, from the parent script, they look fine (as above).

```
print "$jockey\n";
print "$racecourse\n";
print "$racenum\n";
print "$hnamenum\n";
print "$trainer\n";
print "$TDRating\n";
print "$PRO\n";           

AARON LYNCH
WARRNAMBOOL
RACE 1
DAREBIN (8)
ERIC MUSGROVE
B
1
```

When I pass the arguments to the child script (as follows), the arguments are passed incorrectly.

```
system("perl \"$bindir\\narrative4.pl\" $jockey $racecourse $racenum $hnamenum $trainer $TDRating $PRO");

AARON
LYNCH
WARRNAMBOOL
RACE
1
DAREBIN
(8)
```

As you can see, $ARGV[0] becomes AARON, $ARGV[1] becomes LYNCH, $ARGV[2] becomes WARRNAMBOOL, and so on.

I have investigated adding quotes to the arguments using qq, quotemeta and Win32::ShellQuote, unfortunately, even if I pass qq{"$jockey"}, the quotes are still stripped before they reach the child script, so they must be protected in some way.

I not sure if either of the aforementioned solutions is the correct but I'm happy to be corrected.

I'd appreciate any suggestions. Thanks in advance.

Note: I am running this using Strawberry Perl on a Windows 10 PC.
Note2: I purposely left out use strict; & use warnings; in these examples.

Parent Script

```
use Cwd;
$dir = getcwd;
$bin = "bin"; $bindir = "$dir/$bin";

$infile = "FINAL-SORTED-JOCKEY-RIDES-FILE.list";

open (INFILE, "<$infile") or die "Could not open $infile $!\n";

while (<INFILE>)
{
   $line = $_;

   chomp($line);

   my ($jockey, $racecourse, $racenum, $hnamenum, $trainer, $TDRating, $PRO) = split(/,/, $line); 

   print "$jockey\n";
   print "$racecourse\n";
   print "$racenum\n";
   print "$hnamenum\n";
   print "$trainer\n";
   print "$TDRating\n";
   print "$PRO\n";            

   system("perl \"$bindir\\narrative4.pl\" $jockey $racecourse $racenum $hnamenum $trainer $TDRating $PRO");

   sleep (1);
}
close INFILE;

exit;
```

Child Script

```
$passedjockey = $ARGV[0];
$passedracecourse = $ARGV[1];
$passedracenum = $ARGV[2];
$passedhnamenum = $ARGV[3];
$passedtrainer = $ARGV[4];
$passedTDRating = $ARGV[5];
$passedPRO = $ARGV[6];

print "$passedjockey\n";
print "$passedracecourse\n";
print "$passedracenum\n";
print "$passedhnamenum\n";
print "$passedtrainer\n";
print "$passedTDRating\n";
print "$passedPRO\n\n";
```

Comment: Use the list version of `system`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That whole double-quoted string that is passed to `system` is first evaluated and thus all variables are interpolated -- so the intended multi-word arguments become merely words in a list. So in the end the string has a command to run with individual words as arguments.

Then, even if you figure out how to stick which quotes in there just right, so to keep those multi-word arguments "together," there's still a chance of a shell being invoked, in which case those arguments again get broken up into words before being passed to the program.

Instead of all this use the LIST form of [system](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html).  The first argument is then the name of the program that will be directly executed without a shell (see docs for some details on that), and the remaining arguments are passed as they are to that program.

**parent**

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my @args = ('first words', 'another', 'two more', 'final'); 

my $prog = 'print_args.pl';

system($prog, @args) == 0  
    or die "Error w/ system($prog, @args): $!";
```

and the invoked **print_args.pl**

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use feature 'say';

say for @ARGV;
```

The `@ARGV` contains arguments passed to the program at invocation. There's more that can be done to inspect the error, see docs and links in them.<sup>†</sup>

By what you show you indeed don't need a shell and the LIST form is generally easy to recommend as a basic way to use `system`, when the shell isn't needed.  If you were to *need* shell's capabilities for something in that command then you'd have to figure out how to protect those spaces.

---

<sup>†</sup> And then there are modules for running external programs that are far better than `system` & Co.  From ease-of-use to features and power: 
[IPC::System::Simple](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::System::Simple), [Capture::Tiny](https://metacpan.org/pod/Capture::Tiny), [IPC::Run3](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run3), [IPC::Run](https://metacpan.org/pod/IPC::Run).

Comment: Perfect! Thank you so much @zdim And thank you for the detailed explanation and additional info regarding running external programs, etc. I will investigate further. All the best!

Comment: @BillyJ Very glad if it helps :).  A nice thing about using those modules is that there is nothing to it -- look at synopsis in the linked docs and that's all that need be done; one line of code.  And one gets a better thing.  So I absolutely recommend that.  Take care :)